# Why is my data-set reducing while training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, training-data

During training , my data set is reducing . I don't know what is causing it. Ive padded X and used test train split

```
max_features = 4500
X = pad_sequences(sequences = X, maxlen = max_features, padding = 'pre')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 101)
```

X_train.shape

```
(17983, 4500)
```

y_train.shape

```
(17983,)
```

This is my lstm algorithm

```
lstm_model = Sequential(name = 'lstm_nn_model')
lstm_model.add(layer = Embedding(input_dim = max_features, output_dim = 120, name = '1st_layer'))
lstm_model.add(layer = LSTM(units = 120, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0, name = '2nd_layer'))
lstm_model.add(layer = Dropout(rate = 0.5, name = '3rd_layer'))
lstm_model.add(layer = Dense(units = 120,  activation = 'relu', name = '4th_layer'))
lstm_model.add(layer = Dropout(rate = 0.5, name = '5th_layer'))
lstm_model.add(layer = Dense(units = len(set(y)),  activation = 'sigmoid', name = 'output_layer'))
lstm_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


lstm_model_fit = lstm_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 2)
```

[image]
When the epochs starts running , before it was 1/17983.
Now when i re run it's 1/562.
Please note I'm new to this , im just running an existing code to learn.Why is this happening .

Answer (score 1):

When you fit the model with the data, the GPU has to load all data and working with it. If the GPU loads 17983 data simultaneously, it will run out of memory. For this reason, the data are put into 'Batch' which are groups of data that are processed together. The standard size is 32 and if you make 17983/32 = 561.96875 and it is rounded.